# Dummy Update(any DML) command for Oracle for testing

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I would like to know if it is possible to write dummy update command for Oracle for sake of unit testing.

Something similar to

```
        SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: create a dummy table, insert a row into it. Voila, you can update it.

Option 2: create a dummy view, add an "instead of update" trigger to it that does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a table somewhere,

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 'foo'
 WHERE 1 = 0
```